Opensearch cluster health red status
I can see Opersearch cluster health red status and i have deleted all the indexes as it in dev and when ran the below i got the default indexes health is in red status and getting permission error to delete them with master user.. Currently all the indexes are deleted only defaults are there.
curl -X GET -u 'oss-test:xxxxxxxxxxx' 'https://vpc-oss-na-test-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_cat/indices?v'
ealth status index                            uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
red    open   .opensearch-observability        x2qSq8bfRxCgOKaKs7rn-Q   1   1
red    open   .plugins-ml-config               Dir0TcE1Q62CcHS7XWS4_w   5   1
red    open   .opendistro-job-scheduler-lock   kZACwVDyTTKYZABCTTZkiw   5   1
red    open   .kibana_1                        FTcd1sdzQ1iKmzNDOp3KMA   1   1
green  open   .opendistro_security             oA1savWzRXaFIZC7hJKY2g   1   1         10            1      112kb           56kb
red    open   .opensearch-notifications-config 6tJxDaVeRbyPY-lMy5q4Jw   1   1

I tried to delete these and restore but i am getting 'no permissions for [] and User [name=oss-test, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]')
Please suggest what else can do to bring the cluster health to green..
